# How to connect to a different database based on logged in user with LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I will try to be as clear as possible on this Smile | :)

**Situation**
I have one overlooking database, that hold a table with users. Depending on which user logs in, the application should connect to a database that holds more information about that user's organization.

So there are multiple (dynamic) databases where users belong to. All the organizational databases have the same structure of tables but are in separate databases.

**Questions**

- If I would like to work with Linq, is it possible to connect to different databases on-the-fly?
- Can I save the the connection strings of the organizational databases in my overlooking database then or what is best here?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq to Sql - Set connection string dynamically based on environment variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188962/linq-to-sql-set-connection-string-dynamically-based-on-environment-variable)

Comment: How many users are we talking about here? If its in the order of a dozen or less, databases will clearly be an overkill.

Comment: Well, a database is created per organization.. so not per user. There are multiple users per organization. But i think the number of organizations will stay less then a dozen..

Answer (score 0):

Add a bunch of connection strings in your web.config.
Toggle the strings as needed.

Comment: The problem is that the organizations can be managed from the web, so added or deleted... Should i overwrite web.config then?

Comment: store them in a database then

Comment: Well how do i switch between them then? And does linq know the structure then?

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is only a framework to generate queries in SQL or another language based on code you have written in ASP.NET.  The real power of LINQ is it's ability to use different frameworks to produce the queries.   I know of three off the top of my head: Linq to SQL, Entity Framework, and the Telerik Open Access ORM.

In Entity Framework, The situation you've described  is something I had to code for.  The biggest problem is generating a proper "Entity Connection String" from your SQL connection string.  If needed I should be able to provide the bit of code I got from somewhere to switch out the SQL connection string, but it probably does makes some assumptions about the model name, so you might have to tweak it.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a repository for organazation data that has methods with a connection string as one of the arguments. Like

```
public User GetUser(string connectionString, string name)
{
    using(var context = new OrganizationContext(connectionString))
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Where `OrganizationContext` can be a Linq-to-Sql DataContext or an Entity Framework ObjectContext. You may want to use [EntityConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) for the latter.

Storing the connection strings in the overlooking database is probably the best option.