# Dynamically choose DataContext

Tags: c#, asp.net

based on some variable, I want to choose the datacontext from four possible datacontexts (of different types, of course) in a master page and then use it in nested master pages. Is this possible?

Thanks,
Ondrej

Comment: yes, i am, no problem with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether this is work for you.

But I think you can change the `connection` dynamically to your `datacontext`.

You can have a look at [Dynamic connection for LINQ to SQL DataContext](http://steveclements.net/blog/Dynamic-connection-for-LINQ-to-SQL-DataContext) and [Linq to Sql - Set connection string dynamically based on environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188962/linq-to-sql-set-connection-string-dynamically-based-on-environment-variable)

Comment: yep, figured out how to do it with dlinq